# Is there a better way to pass context to a helper kotlin class?

Tags: android, kotlin

My application consists of three classes :

- class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
- class Map : Fragment() , OnMapReadyCallback
- class DataWriter(val context: Context): AppCompatActivity()

**Map** contains google map methods and **DataWriter** contains File writer methods as long with a write storage permission check on runtime ***IsWriteEnabled()***.

I call **IsWriteEnabled()** from **Map** so I can check If I have permissions with the following way:

```
class Map : Fragment() , OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mdataWriter: DataWriter

// a lot of code removed

 override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mdataWriter = DataWriter(requireContext())
        mdataWriter.isWriteEnable()
    }
```

here is my DataWriter.kt

```
class DataWriter(val context: Context): AppCompatActivity(){

    fun isWriteEnable(): Boolean { 
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,   
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                context as Activity,
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                ),
                WRITE_REQUEST_CODE
            )
        } else {
            Log.e("DB", "PERMISSION GRANTED")
        }
        return true
    }
```

## My question

Is there a better way to pass context to a class that its not attached to main activity?
Is the call to the method as it should be?

Comment: Why is `DataWriter` extending `AppCompatActivity`? Just to request permissions? You shouldn't do this. If it's not an Activity, you should not extend any `Activity` kind of class.  Just ask for the permission either in `Map` or `MainActivity`.

Comment: @RicardoCosteira inside there some more methods to write csv and start stop logging. Shouldnt do that?

Comment: Do whatever you want with the class, just don't extend an Android component if it's not supposed to do the job of that component. You're adding a lot of complexity to the class with no need whatsoever.

Comment: I am trying to split the methods to different classes so the code lines dont become increase too much. is it a wrong approach?

Comment: Splitting methods is good, as long as the methods are in classes that should be responsible for them. By extending `AppCompatActivity`, you're already inheriting a bunch of methods that have nothing to do with `DataWriter`. In this case, you're ask for the permission through something called **Activity**Compat. In other words, you're only supposed to use ActivityCompat in something that is supposed to be able to used it, like an `Activity` or `Fragment` (as components that handle user interaction, asking for permissions is actually a responsibility of the `Activity` or `Fragment`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are free to pass a `Context` to a class that its not attached to an `Activity` in any way you like. Passing it through the class's constructor is a good practice (dependency injection), but only in the case where your class needs a `Context` to fully function correctly. If you need a `Context` to use only in a specific method, might as well pass it as an argument to the method.

The most important thing you have to be aware here is that an `Activity` has a finite life cycle. If you keep a reference to an `Activity Context` in a class that will outlive that `Activity`, you will create a memory leak: the garbage collector will not be able to destroy that `Activity` because there's a reference to it somewhere. This is why people usually prefer to handle an `Application Context` instead, which will always outlive any class you can create.

Now, a correction to your code: don't extend `AppCompatActivity` just to inherit `ActivityCompat`. By extending `AppCompatActivity`, you're granting the class access to a lot of life cycle management, resource handling and user interaction methods that have nothing to do with your class. `AppCompatActivity` is supposed to be extended by `Activities` **only**. Otherwise, its name would not end with **Activity** :)

As components that handle user interaction, asking for permissions is a responsibility of the `Activity` or `Fragment`, so just ask for the permission either in `Map` or `MainActivity`. Also, I'm assuming that `Map` is indeed doing what a `Fragment` is supposed to do, and you're not just extending `Fragment` to get access to some `Fragment` methods :)

Comment: so ```class DataWriter(val context: Context)``` if I want to pass the context through the constructor

Comment: or ```fun isWriteEnable(context: Context): Boolean ``` if I want to send context as an argument to my method

Comment: Yup, that's about it :) just remember that if that method is supposed to check a permission, it should go into the `Activity` or `Fragment`.